# Is event ID in MS Graph API unique?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is the ID of the [event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) unique across all user calendars? Or is the uniqueness only within a calendar?

In other words: Can the appointment **"Foo"** in the calendar of **user A** and the appointment **"Bar"** in the calendar of **user B** have the same ID? Or is the event ID unique across the calendars?

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but hopefully helpful.

Based on [this very old answer for the EWS API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/5a746aa7-ee58-4edd-8a8e-43c501da2242/ews-managed-api-how-unique-is-the-uniqueid-of-an-appointment-item-does-it-survive-a-migration-from) that shares the same data storage for events in Microsoft Graph, and the fact I haven't seen a post that contradicts my old statement, I suspect that it is unique across all user calendars.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good to me. But since the matter is very important to us, a definitive answer would be great. Would it be possible to get a clear statement here? Who else can I turn to?

Comment: I have seen cases where the Event Id is NOT unique across users. e.g. multiple people attending the same event. Some were unique, but others were not so in the mean time I've just concatenated the Id, StartDate and User Id then base64 encoded them to get another Id just to get my process going. Would be happy to see a better way of doing this. I'm sure I also used iCalUId and that didn't get unique values for that either.